# Load data in to text fields after changing combo box JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to get the value from the combo box (selected ID) and retrieve data from the database and populate values in to text fields.. 
I have done this by using javascrit / XML   for PHP. but as I am new to  JSP i'm facing difficulties with that. 
 In php i used  2 files, java script and the php file to write down the response. Bus it there any way we can write all in one jsp page n get the values.

this is my combo box

```
<select class="cmbCourse" name="cmbStudent" id="cmbStudent" onchange="loadStudent();">
  <option value="">--Select Student ID--</option>
    <% conn = DBConnection.connect();
           stm = conn.createStatement();
           rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT stuId from student");
           while (rs.next()) {%>
   <option value="<%=rs.getString("stuId")%>"><%=rs.getString("stuId")%></option>
  <% }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this i hope it may helpful to you

http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Ajax/25155-combo-box-value-.html